# socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed while connecting to ngrok server

Tags: sockets, tcp, client-server, ngrok

I wrote a simple server code using socket module forward the listening port using ngrok but when i try to connect to ngrok provided url it gives error

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

**Server Code**

```
import socket

server = socket.socket()
host = "localhost"
port = 5002
server.bind((host,port))
print("Started Listening.........")
server.listen()
con, addr = server.accept()
print("Connection is accepted from :",str(addr))
while True:
    data = con.recv(1024).decode()
    if not data:
        break
    print("From Connected User :",str(data))
    data = str(data).upper()
    print("Received from User: " + str(data))
    data = input("Enter message::::")
    con.send(data.encode())
con.close()
```

**Client Code**

```
import socket

host = "tcp://0.tcp.in.ngrok.io:18376"
port = 5002

client = socket.socket()
client.connect((host,port))
mess = input("Enter message::")
while mess!='q':
    client.send(mess.encode())
    data = client.recv(1024).decode()
    print("FROM SERVER = ",data)
    mess = input("Enter message ::")
client.close()
```

I am creating a tcp tunnel using ngrok at 5002 port

```
ngrok tcp 5002
```

**It generates**

```
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040                                                                                    
Forwarding                    tcp://0.tcp.in.ngrok.io:18376 -> localhost:5002
```

i am using this tcp url in my client host code `host = "tcp://0.tcp.in.ngrok.io:18376"` I tried removing port number and tried only `tcp://0.tcp.in.ngrok.io` but nothing happend

Can you guide me how to connect to this tcp tunnel from socket module because i am pretty new to socket programming.

Comment: *"tcp://0.tcp.in.ngrok.io:18376"* - this is not a host nameusable in `connect` - that's why you get this error. The hostname is `0.tcp.in.ngrok.io`, the port is 18376

Comment: @SteffenUllrich tried this but still getting the same error

Comment: *" tried this "* - what exactly did you try. Show the code.

Comment: instead of host I wrote ```0.tcp.in.ngrok.io``` and in port I wrote ```18376``` in client code

Comment: if `connect('0.tcp.in.ngrok.io', 18376)` fails with `getaddrinfo failed` then you have a DNS problem outside of your application. If the error is something different please state it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i am still  getting error of ```getaddrinfo failed```